# No such file or directory when running a python script in WSL

Tags: python, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to run a python script in WSL that runs Ubuntu.

In WSL, the following command does not work:

```
admin:/mnt/c/Users/admin$ /mnt/c/Users/admin/repo/env/Scripts/python.exe /mnt/c/Users/admin/repo/script.py
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe: can't open file '/mnt/c/Users/admin/repo/script.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

However, the following individual commands work:

```
admin:/mnt/c/Users/admin$ /mnt/c/Users/admin/repo/env/Scripts/python.exe repo/script.py
```

```
admin:/mnt/c/Users/admin$ /mnt/c/Users/admin/repo/env/Scripts/python.exe
```

```
admin:/mnt/c/Users/admin$ cat /mnt/c/Users/admin/repo/script.py
```

Why am I seeing this strange behavior? How do I run a python script using absolute path?

Comment: use tab to autocomplete the path ... make sure your venv is created from python in the wsl (not the windows python) ... you call it with abs path exactly as you have

Comment: @JoranBeasley I didn't know I needed another python created in wsl.. Now it works. Thanks!